# Showing $P[X_1<\cdots < X_n] = 1/n!$ when $X_i$ do not have densities.

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose $(X_i)_i$ are independent and identically distributed from the same continuous distribution. If the distribution is absolutely continuous (i.e. the $X_i$ have density functions)  then showing $P[X_1<\cdots< X_n]= \frac{1}{n!}$ follows quickly from Fubini's theorem and a counting argument.

How can one show this fact without using density functions?

Comment: To clarify, are the $X_i$ also supposed to be independent?  If not, how do you exclude situations like $X_2 \equiv X_1$?

Comment: Yes, of course, I meant to say IID.

Comment: If the common distribution has a discrete part, the probability is $\lt1/n!$. Are you interested in distributions with no discrete part but not purely densitable?

Comment: What does "continuous distribution" mean if it doesn't mean absolutely continuous?

Comment: @ChrisEagle Without atoms.

Comment: This should be true under the weaker condition of exchangeability (provided that the joint cdf is continuous). There are $n!$ permutations of the $X_i$'s, so $n!$ possible orderings, and all are equally likely. Moreover, because the random variables are jointly continuous, there are no ties w.p. 1, so the random variables have a strict ordering with probability one, hence $\frac 1 {n!}$ for each ordering.

Comment: @guy "and all are equally likely" you just assumed the conclusion. The point of this question is to prove that they are all equally likely. Obvious from intuition, but nontrivial to show.

Comment: @nullUser well, the point of the comment was that you could weaken independence, not to prove anything. You already provided the details on how to make it rigorous, I just thought I would mention that the conditions could be weakened...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured it out myself. Firstly, let us show $P[X_i=X_j]=0$ for $i\neq j$. Let $F(t)$ denote the common cdf, by assumption $F$ is continuous. Partition $[0,1]$ into $n$ equal width subintervals, and let $A_{n,1},\ldots, A_{n,n}$ denote the preimages of these intervals under $F$. Then $P[A_{n,k}] = 1/n$ for all $n$. For all $n$ we have $$\{X_i=X_j\} \subseteq \cup_{k=1}^n\{X_i \in A_{n,k}, X_j \in A_{n,k}\}$$
and so
$$
P[X_i=X_j] \leq \sum_{k=1}^nP[X_i \in A_{n,k}, X_j \in A_{n,k}] = \sum_{k=1}^nP[X_i \in A_{n,k}]P[X_j \in A_{n,k}] = n \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{1}{n}
$$
and taking the limit as $n \to \infty$ shows $P[X_i=X_j]=0$.

In light of the previous fact, we have $$\sum_{\sigma \in S_n} P[X_{\sigma(1)} < \cdots < X_{\sigma(n)}] = 1.$$

We then consider that for $N>n$ we may choose any $n$ distinct $A_{N,k_1},\ldots,A_{N,k_n}$ (where the $k_i$ are increasing) and then the event $$\{X_1 \in A_{N,k_1}, \ldots, X_n \in A_{N,k_n}\} \subseteq \{X_1 < \cdots < X_n\} $$
There are ${N \choose n}$ distinct choices for $k_1,\ldots,k_n$ and the corresponding events are disjoint and have probability $\frac{1}{N^n}$, so
$$
\frac{1}{N^n}{N \choose n} \leq P[X_1 < \cdots < X_n]
$$
and taking the limit as $N \to \infty$ gives
$$
\frac{1}{n!} \leq P[X_1 < \cdots < X_n].
$$
The same argument of course applies for any $\sigma \in S_n$, and summing them shows that none of the inequalities can be strict, else the sum would exceed $1$. Hence $ P[X_1 < \cdots < X_n]=\frac{1}{n!}$.